# failed building wheel for *python package*

Tags: package

I'm trying to install the package numpy using pip

I open up cmd, standing in C:/Python34/Scripts I type: "pip install numpy" and it tries to install it (A bunch of white text shows up).

Inbetween the white text there is a red line saying "Failed building wheel for numpy", and at the end there is a bunch of incoherent red text which says something about error 1.

This happens with all packages, thoughts? It says it is trying to install a cached version of numpy, could that be the problem? How do I empy the cache?

**EDIT:** seems to be only happening with numpy, but since many other packages require numpy, the too fail to install.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me too. I was trying to update pandas to address a reported bug fixed in the newer version. But when I tried upgrading I ran into your error with a message about requiring Visual C++ 2010 (which I already had).

Now, I tried downloading the executable from SourceForge and installing that way  - but then I got error messages and realized I was in over my head.

I decided on a brute force method - simply upgrade to the newest Anaconda/Python version. Now this may not be an option for you but it worked for me. I just updated [Anaconda first](http://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install#updating-from-older-anaconda-versions) and  **it works for me!**.

May not have gained any understanding, but the problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

I install python3-pip,but 404 error...

So,I try

*apt-get install python3-scipy*

success

Comment: 'I'm trying to install the package numpy using pip' is the OP's question. You first install scipy (even _using_ pip) and then install pip? Can you please elaborate why your steps are an answer to this question?

Comment: I install tensorflow ,but it need pip3,then I apt install python3-pip,but " http://mirrors.ustc.edu.cn/ubuntu-ports xenial-security/main arm64 libexpat1-dev arm64 2.1.0-7ubuntu0.16.04.2
  404  Not Found [IP: 202.141.160.110 80]"  error,so I install python3-scipy to solve it

Comment: Note that installing via apt-get is [different from installation via pip](https://askubuntu.com/a/431811/490799) (and may or may not suit your needs).

Answer (score -1):

I have run into this kind of the problem and tried some solutions found on the web, which didn't work. I guess there may be something about version of scipy or some unknown dependences...

So, I typed

`sudo dnf install python3-scipy`

and that did the trick.

I found that scipy needs `lapack` and `python3-numpy-f2py`, which are not listed on its dependences.

And then I typed `sudo pip3 install python3-scipy`. It printed red text:

> Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement python3-scipy
>   (from versions: ) No matching distribution found for python3-scipy.